# Bitwise operation to compare a length subset of two bit streams

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

The "length" least significant bits of one address shall be compared with the "length" least significant bits of another address.
Can some one help me in getting the best optimal solution for the same?

***Example:***

```
address1 = 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
address2 = 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1
```

If the comparison bits are 00100 then the above two addresses are same.

Comment: What does "Mask least significant bits" mean? The concept of "mask" is well-known, but what is that reference to "least significant" doing there?

Comment: As in when the mask is 00100 or 4 integer value, the 4 LSBs of both address should be compared.

Comment: Er.... Sorry, that is not a *mask*. Stop calling it a mask. "Mask" is an established term with very specific meaning. What you need has nothing to do with any masks. You want to compare `N` least-significant bits. That's what you want. No masks here.

Comment: If you want to compare `4` least-significant bits, then its just `4` least-significant bits. There's no point in representing that `4` as `00100`. It achieves absolutely nothing and only confuses people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, you want to compare `N` least-significant bits. In that case your `N` is not a mask. "Mask" is an established term with very specific meaning. Your `N` is not a mask. It is just number of bits you have to compare.

To achieve that, you can start with actually generating a real mask from your `N`. This

```
uintptr_t mask = 1;
mask = (mask << N) - 1;
```

will create a mask that has `1`s in `N` least-significant binary positions. (I don't know what type you use to store your addresses. That's the type you should use in place of `uintptr_t`.)

Then you can use that mask to compare your addresses

```
(address1 & mask) == (address2 & mask)
```

or

```
((address1 ^ address2) & mask) == 0
```

---

Alternatively, you can solve the same problem without using any masks at all. If your addresses have `M` bits total, then the comparison can be expressed as

```
(address1 << (M - N)) == (address2 << (M - N))
```

Answer (score 2):

As @AndreyT wrote, you really are not describing a mask.

Trying to guess what you really do mean, here's my best attempt:
*(assuming your int-size is 32-bits.  You can convert to sizeof() or use 64 as appropriate)*
*(untested, but reasonably well commented, so you can test and fix it yourself)*

```
void Compare(int addrA, int addrB, int nBits)
{
    // This is all 1s in binary.
    unsigned int mask = 0xFFFFFFFF;  

    mask = mask >> (32-nBits);
    // Example: if nBits = 4
    // then 32-4 = 28 and 
    // Mask == [1111] >> 28 == 28-zeros... followed by 4 Ones

    if ((addrA & mask) == (addrB & mask))
    {
        printf("Same\n");
    } else
    {
        printf("Not the same\n");
    }
}
```

**Sample Call**

```
int main(void)
{
   int address1 = 0x2A09;  // 00000000 0010 1010 0000 1001
   int address2 = 0x2A19;  // 00000000 0010 1010 0001 1001

   Compare(address1, address2, 4);
}
```

Comment: As in when the mask is 00100 or 4 integer value, the 4 LSBs of both address should be compared. So the output should not be in comparing the third least bits

Answer (score 0):

to turn the number 4 (or 00100) into the mask you want, you need

```
#define MASK(n)     ((1 << (n)) - 1)
```

Also, if you are going to quote a binary representation of an integer, in C use 0b100, then we know you mean 4. 00100 is an octal constant.